# Bean to bean values

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I have received some help on how beans work, so far i have an xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

  <bean id= "currentDateService" class ="xx.CurrentDateServiceImpl" />
    <bean id= "CurrentDateServiceFormat" class ="xx.CurrentDateServiceFormatImpl">
     <property name="service" ref="currentDateService"/>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

A simple method to obtain the current date:

```
public class CurrentDateServiceImpl implements CurrentDateService {
    public LocalDate getCurrentDate() {
        return LocalDate.now() ;

    }   
}
```

And i am currently working on formating the current date i receive:

```
public class CurrentDateServiceFormatImpl implements CurrentDateServiceFormat{


    private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");

    CurrentDateService service;

    public String formatCurrentDate(){
       return service.getCurrentDate().format(formatter); 
    }

    public void setService(CurrentDateService service){
       this.service = service;
    }
}
```

My test is:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:src/main/resources/META-INF/application-context.xml" })
public class CurrentDateServiceImplTest {

@Autowired
CurrentDateService service; 
CurrentDateServiceFormat service2;


    @Test
    public void test() {

        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
        System.out.println(service);
        System.out.println(service2);
        LocalDate date2 = service.getCurrentDate(); 
        assertEquals(date, date2);
    }

}
```

But the service2 i get printed out is null, thus im unable to run service2.formatCurrentDate, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Also note that if you are just learning Spring, you should learn the JavaConfig way of doing things - XML based configuration is only there for legacy purposes and not long for this world...

Comment: Are there any good tutorials you could suggest for learning the JavaConfig way?

Comment: One of the easiest starting points is the [new Spring Boot](http://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) automatic bootstrapper. Otherwise, there's plenty of information [in the reference documents](http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch03.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss the `@Autowired` annotation for the `service2` object. Add it and it should work.